# Why showing jason string in my footer section after installing woocommerce plugin in my WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am learning WordPress ecommerce theme development. I am facing peculiar issue after installing woocommerce pluging in my theme. It is showing jason string in my footer section. like

{"@context":"https://schema.org/","@type":"Product","@id":"http://localhost/wordpress/product/wordpress-pennant/#product","name":"WordPress Pennant","url":"http://localhost/wordpress/product/wordpress-pennant/","description":"This is an external product.","image":"http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/pennant-1.jpg","sku":"wp-pennant","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","price":"11.05","priceValidUntil":"2022-12-31","priceSpecification":{"price":"11.05","priceCurrency":"USD","valueAddedTaxIncluded":"false"},"priceCurrency":"USD","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","url":"http://localhost/wordpress/product/wordpress-pennant/","seller":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Brand Bangladesh","url":"http://localhost/wordpress"}}]}

I have tried many times to fix it.

Comment: Seems like there is some code in your theme which is echoing or printing the json code. It may be in functions.php, footer.php, etc. 
I can only tell after seeing the theme files

Comment: Can you please send me the list of active plugins you have? and if you have any debugging settings ON.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your issue is that a plugin (or code), is displaying the Schema details of that product on the page. this might happen if you manually place this code without having knowledge about how to insert a 'schema' on the page, or maybe you have a plugin that is doing this. Try to deactivate any plugin that you're using for placing 'schema' code on your page.

Comment: Thanks for anser.  But there has no extera plugin installed. Only it will occoured when woocommerce installed.